# Observe a livedata inside viewmodel at init

Tags: android, kotlin, mvvm

So everytime my app starts up, I fetch a `User` document from firestore if user is logged in. This documents contains all the information regarding the user. I have to show this information in various activities throughout the app.

Now, I don't want to `observe` the document every time I want to show user's data in any fragment/activity. So, I keep a local copy of the document inside my `UserViewModel` as a Kotlin data class which can be used immediatly to show user data (no async calls). Here, is the problem though, If the user's document gets updated I want the changes to be reflected in my local copy, to do this I want to observe the document inside my ViewModel. Here's is some of my code:

```
fun observeUserProfile(userId: String): MutableLiveData<User> {
        val res = MutableLiveData<User>()

        DatabaseService.getDbInstance()
            .collection("users")
            .document(userId)
            .addSnapshotListener { snap, e ->
                if (e != null) {
                    Log.d("UserRepository", "Error while observing $userId, error: $e")
                }

                if (snap != null && snap.exists()) {
                    res.value = CustomUtils.convertToUser(snap)
                    Log.d("UserRepo", "Fetched user: ${res.value}")
                } else res.value = null
            }

        return res
    }
```

This function observes the document. Here, is my ViewModel `init` function:

```
val currentUid = MutableLiveData<String>()
var currentUser = MutableLiveData<User>()

init {
    val uid = application.getSharedPreferences("myappd", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
        .getString("user_uid", null)

    if (uid != null) {
        currentUid.value = uid
        currentUser = observeUser(uid) // Think the problem is here
    }
}
```

I receive `NullPointerException`s alot of times when I do `userViewModel.currentUser.value`. My idea behind doing this is to have a local copy which i can show immediately instead of observing everytime, while also keeping the local copy updated to the firestore document. Do in need to create a LiveData for current user? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Why do you return MutableLiveData from `observeUserProfile`?

Maybe it will be better to set `currentUser` live data value in this function:

```
val currentUid = MutableLiveData<String>()
val currentUser = MutableLiveData<User>()

init {
    val uid = application.getSharedPreferences("myappd", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
        .getString("user_uid", null)

    if (uid != null) {
        currentUid.value = uid
        observeUser(uid)
    }
}

fun observeUserProfile(userId: String) {
        DatabaseService.getDbInstance()
            .collection("users")
            .document(userId)
            .addSnapshotListener { snap, e ->
                if (e != null) {
                    Log.d("UserRepository", "Error while observing $userId, error: $e")
                }

                if (snap != null && snap.exists()) {
                    currentUser.value = CustomUtils.convertToUser(snap)
                }
            }
}
```

In this case, we can observe `currentUser` value and if we get value at observeUserProfile it's immediately will be delivered to observers.

Comment: This looks right but `observeUserProfile` is on a seperate class in seperate file, how do I pass current user's refernce to that file?

Comment: Maybe, in this case, you could pass a class with `observeUserProfile` to your `ViewMode`l constructor?

Comment: I mean how do I pass the `currentUser` variable to the method `observeUserProfile` so i can do `currentUser.value = CustomUtils.convertToUser(snap)`, sorry for being unclear

Comment: How about to pass a lambda to `observeUserProfile` like this `observeUserProfile(userId: String, onUpdate: (User) -> Unit)`? And this lambda will be look like `{currentUser.value = it}`